# tar diff: get file names only

Tags: linux, tar, archive

Using GNU tar, when I do `tar df books.tar.bz2`, I might get the following verbose result:

```
books/a.pdf: Mod time differs
books/a.pdf: Size differs
books/b.pdf: Mod time differs
books/b.pdf: Size differs
```

Is there any convenient way to get the following output instead?

```
a.pdf b.pdf
```

The reason is simply that I want to use the output of `tar df ...` to create another archive that contains just the files that have changed, e.g., using `gtar cfvj books-updated.tar.bz2 a.pdf b.pdf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combo like this:

```
tar -df archive.tar | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort -u
```

`tar -df` get changed files (you already have that)

`awk -F: '{print $1}'` print only first 'column'

`sort -u` remove duplicates

EDIT: following the @roaima's input, if you need to match files which themselves contain colons (or spaces) in their names you can substitute `awk` part with this one

```
sed 's/\(.*\):.*/\1/'
```

this will effectively show only filenames until the last occurrence of a colon (which is at the end of the first column)

Comment: Filenames can contain colons (and spaces) - `touch 'a.pdf: Size differs'; ls a.pdf*`

Comment: In that case a more flexible option would be to use sed instead of awk so you can regex what you want

Comment: Maybe `sed 's/\(.*\): .*/\1/'` to keep everything before the last `: `.

Comment: lol just as i was writing the edit

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at `star`?

You could use:

```
star -diff -tpath < archive.tar
```

The option `-tpath` makes the diference.

The most recent version of star is in schilytools.